# LG W2243S drivers for windows 7

Tags: drivers

Can anyone tell me where can I find drivers for LG W2243S.
I'm using Windows 7 64bit.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you even check LG's website for the drivers? Half a minute of google searching gave me this: http://www.lg.com/ae/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=W2243S-PF&initialTab=drivers&targetPage=support-product-profile

If you have already tried the above driver, maybe you should post any errors you got.